Getting Two Character Variable Without Pressing Enter (PowerShell/ CMD)
Bash Script:
#! /bin/bash
read -n 2 -p '2 digit:' ans;
echo $ans

When i finish input two character, the script continue, without waiting me to press enter.
And what I have pressed saves to the variable $ans.
If i press A2 for example, value $ans is A2.

Does powershell or cmd have features like the bash mentioned above?
Getting a two character variable without pressing enter (from Choice/Read-Host/set /p/ or else).
As far as I know, choice is limited to only 1 character.
Meanwhile, Read-Host (PowerShell) or set /p (cmd) requires pressing enter.
Or maybe there are other features that I don't know yet.

you could easily enough make your own function to append an input character to a string N timens

Yes. If there really isn't a feature like this in the Windows, I will create my own function for this. Thanks

What keys does the function need to support? will input always be alphanumerical, or is support for other printable ascii characters desired as well?

for basic, maybe alphanumerical only.

With batch, you may only ask for a string and then truncate it to two
characters. The user will need to press Enter to finish entering the string.
I assume that you would like for the script to continue automatically
after the two characters are entered, without the need to press Enter.
This is possible using the PowerShell
Console.ReadKey Method.
Your code may look something like :
$InputChar1 = [console]::ReadKey()
$InputChar2 = [console]::ReadKey()


You could do it like this too: $test = $([console]::ReadKey();[console]::ReadKey())

According both your answer, i think what i want like this $test = -join $(@([console]::ReadKey();[console]::ReadKey()) | % KeyChar)

Is also possible to display additional text during input ? like in Bash above -p '2 digit:' or like in Choice /m "2 digit:" or in cmd set /p ans=2 digit: ?

Sure. write-host "This is some text: " -nonewline -foregroundcolor yellow is an example

So it's also possible in PowerShell, although it requires a long script. Not as simple as Bash

Indeed. In powershell, people often just use $var = read-host "Put in something here:" but it does require the user to press enter. You can create a new function that simulates bash's read, but then you have to have that function somewhere in your script. Its possible to create a powershell module that always loads, and then that function is always available to you. Anyone else will need to install your module too then though.

Good idea. I will create a function for this to make it simple to use. Thank you.

As documentation of what I have done. Maybe it's useful for those who need it.
choice is limited to one character, and Read-Host or set /p requires pressing enter.
Therefore, this script is useful if there are many options that cannot use the default choice and don't like pressing enter.
If there are a lot of menu options, then the alternative is to use a two-character choice, either in cmd or powershell.
Thanks to everyone who has helped via answers or comments.
- CMD
@echo off
:choice2
CLS
set KEYS=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
set K3YS= %KEYS%
choice /n /c %K3YS% /m "Choose: "
call set KEY1=%%K3YS:~%errorlevel%,1%%
CLS
choice /n /c %K3YS% /m "Choose: "
call set KEY2=%%K3YS:~%errorlevel%,1%%
CLS

set KEY=%KEY1%%KEY2%
echo Your Choice '%KEY%'
pause
goto :choice2

- PowerShell
function choice2 {
    CLS 
    $KEYS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
    choice /n /c $KEYS /m 'Choose: '
    $KEY1 = $KEYS[($LastExitCode -1)]
    CLS
    choice /n /c $KEYS /m 'Choose: '
    $KEY2 = $KEYS[($LastExitCode -1)]
    CLS
    
    $KEY = -join @($KEY1; $KEY2)
    "Your Choice `'$($KEY)`'"
    pause
    choice2
}
choice2

Using [console]::ReadKey() simpler
function read {
    CLS
    write-host 'Choose:' -nonewline
    $KEY = -join $(@([console]::ReadKey();[console]::ReadKey()) | Foreach KeyChar)
    CLS
    "Your Choice `'$($KEY)`'"
    pause
    read
}
read

